# Simple and ugly - How to change div position?

Tags: javascript

How can i change the position of the element below

```
<div  style="z-index:101;  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 324px; width: 20px; height:450px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;" id="wrapper" >Content</div>
```

To "left: 100px; top: 100px;"

I don't need a complex function, only a easy solution.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
div.style.left = '100px';
div.style.top = '100px';
```